# give special prices only for products uploaded in one month

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules, promotions, special-price

we uploaded some 1000 products to our site.

we uploaded 500 products in 1st month and next 500 products in 2nd month

now we want to give special prices for products that we uploaded in 1st month.

so we want to use promotions > catalog price rules to give special prices for products uploaded only in first month.

is there any way that we can give special prices for products uploaded in 1st month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as your question, you want to apply the catalog rules for those products which has created in first month.

That means in this case you need to use product attribute `created_at` and using this attribute,you need to apply the catalog rules.

### Solution:

**Step1:** create a new product attribute `my_attribute` and make `sure` that `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` field should be`Yes`.

**Step2:** `Export list of product skus` which has been `created at  the time of 1st` using Magento `default export system` (`admin>system>Export/Import>Export`)

**Step3:** Then `basic step2`,`create` a `csv with sku,my_attribute`. put **my_attribute** `value 1`. Then import this csv using `magento default import   system` .

**Step4:**  As `my_attribute` has been enable at promo, Now you can easy see the attribute to Catalog price rules condition attribute list and just put it value 1.

Now it will works

Comment: i will try this solution @amit, thanks.....

Comment: when i checked attributes list , i did't saw "created_at" atribute code

when i tried to create an attribute  with the attribute code "created_at",i am getting message :

 same code already exists. 

step 1) so what i did is i created attribute with code " my_attribute "

step 2) than i went here : admin>system>Export/Import>Export

Comment: than i saw "my_attribute" under "attribute codes"

than i selected check box which is present left to "my-attribute" and clicked "continue" and downoaded excel sheet.

than i got  all skus of the site, 

i can get all skus which created at 1st month and than i can do step 3 and step 4.

fianlly i have to use "promotions > Catalog price rules" and i have to apply promtion rule with 

condition : "my_attribute is 1"

am i right?

Comment: created_at is magento system field ,you cannot see it on Admin panel

Comment: thanks a lot for @Amit, i created "my_attribute" attribute and than i used promotions > catalog > price rules > than i selected conditiob "my-attribute" is 1 and than updated my_attribute value 1 to first month products using manage products > update attributes, now its fine.....

Comment: you are welcome